# How to hide celery flower tornado server if use nginx

Tags: nginx, celery, flower

I user celery flower as a daemon, and nginx as proxy for it. 
Flower uses port 5555.
Nginx serves it on url `flower.mysite.com`, and uses basic auth.
But flower still avaiable on `mysite.com:5555`, how could I make this url secure?

Answer (score 3):

If you have nginx and your daemon on the same server, simply make your daemon listen on 127.0.0.1 and make nginx forward the requests to that address. It won't be available to any other user besides localhost. Simple and effective.

Answer (score 1):

You need to block incoming connections using `iptables` if you google it you'll find a simple line to do it.

Sorry I don't know `iptables` syntax, I usually just google it my self

Answer (score 0):

what's your operating system? If you're running Ubuntu you can just use [ufw](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.10/serverguide/firewall.html). I usually have the following roles in my provisioning scripts for servers:

```
ufw allow ssh
ufw allow http
ufw allow https
ufw logging off
echo 'y' | ufw enable
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the answer from alfredocambera:

Starting flower with a specific address will bind it to that address only, e.g.:

`flower --address=127.0.0.1`